# CSV file upload with comma value using Php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I was working on the eCommerce site and uploading the CSV file in the PHP database of Size that having the comma. The outcome of the result is the database is coming up with backward slash and double-quotes.
Please help me in rectifying that issue as had wasted my two days working on it.

CSV Format in notepad

```
Product Name,Footware Size
Shirt,"""35,36,34"""
```

Image of my csv file

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MzN5.png)

But it saved in the table 
[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSeJD.png)

Code OF upload CSV File into the database

```
if($_FILES['csv_file']['name'])
{
 $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['csv_file']['name']);
 if(end($filename) == "csv")
 {
  $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
  $find_header = 0;
  while($data = fgetcsv($handle,6000,",",'"'))
  {
      $find_header++;
      if($find_header > 1){
       $name = $database->escape_string($data[0]);
       $foot_size = trim(addslashes($data[2]), '"');;
       $products = new Product();
       $products->product_name = $name;
       $products->created_at = $time;
       $products->updated_at = $time;
       $result = $products->save();
      if($result){
            $product_id = $products->id;

            if(!empty($foot_size)){
                $sizes = explode(',', $foot_size);
                $size_str = '';
                foreach($sizes as $size){
                    $size_str .= $size.',';

                }
                $p_size = rtrim($size_str,",");

                $product_size = new FootSize();
                $product_size->product_id = $product_id;
                $product_size->foot_size = $p_size;
                $product_size->date = $time;
                $product_size->save();
            }

      }
      }

  }
 if($result === true){
   $session->message('Product File Uploaded Successfully.');
   fclose($handle);

  redirect_to('add_product_csv');

 }
 }
 else
 {
  $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select CSV File only</label>';
 }
}
```

Comment: The image of the CSV looks as though you are loading it into a spreadsheet.  These can interpret the contents and don't always show the actual file contents.  Try showing the actual CSV (use something like notepad) and add this text to the question.

Comment: I did the change check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

You have an error in this line:

```
$foot_size = trim(addslashes($data[2]), '"');
```

What it does is to first escape double quotes:

```
"35,36,34" --> \"35,36,34\"
```

And then trim them:

```
\"35,36,34\" --> \"35,36,34\
```

**Solution**

Depending on if you actually want to have the quotes stored in your DB or not, call either `trim` or `addslahes` (but not both) or none of the two:

Strip quotes:

```
$foot_size = trim($data[2], '"');
```

Keep quotes:

```
$foot_size = $data[2];

# your framework *might* require explicitly escaping of quote chars:
$foot_size = addslashes($data[2]);

# even better:
$foot_size = $database->escape_string($data[2]);
```